# @properties - Memory Management

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, properties

would this code be ok concerning memory management?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id object;
...
id anObject = [[Object alloc] init];
self.object = anObject;
id otherObject = [[Object alloc] init];
self.object = otherObject;
```

Thanks for your answers,
Christian

Answer (score 2):

No. As the property descriptor indicates, it will retain the object when it's assigned. So, as you're allocating it, you'll have two retains in your object at the moment of assign it to `self.object`. So, you have to release it:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id object;
...
id anObject = [[Object alloc] init];
self.object = anObject;
[anObject release];

id otherObject = [[Object alloc] init];
self.object = otherObject;
[otherObject release];
...
at dealloc:
self.object = nil;
```

Good luck!

Comment: I prefer to use convenience methods when available, and when not, i always do [[[Class alloc] init] autorelease]. Seems prettier than having an additional line that releases the object which seems weird. But i suppose that's a matter of taste

Comment: It's also a matter of creating autoreleased objects. Say the OP's code was in a tight loop: you'd be much better off explicitly releasing than building up tons of autoreleased memory.